# How to send whole row of data in my spreadsheet via email based on single cell edit (Google Script / GAS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have set up a workflow spreadsheet that has job information such as client name, job details etc. I have a nifty script that hides a whole row if you choose "Complete" from a drop down menu in the final column of that row.

What I am trying to do now is send an email with all the data in the row we are hiding.

UPDATED: Here is the code I have so far:

```
/** 
* TITLE:
*     Hide a row if a value is inputted then send an email 
*/

//**GLOBALS**
// Sheet the data is on.
var SHEET = "Live Jobs";
// The value that will cause the row to hide. 
var VALUE = "Complete";
// The column we will be using 
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 22

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Ensure on correct sheet.
  if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();

    //Ensure we are looking at the correct column.
    if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){
      //If the cell matched the value we require,hide the row. 
      if(cellValue == VALUE){
        activeSheet.hideRow(cell)
        SendEmail(e);
      };
    };
  };
}



/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function SendEmail(e) {
  // Fetch the email address
var correctSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Live Jobs');
var emailRange = correctSheet.getRange('Z1');  
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var cell = sheet.getActiveCell()
var rowValue = cell.getRow();  

  var startRow = rowValue; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, 1, 5);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var message = row; // Second column
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Now, the hide row works, and the email function works if I run it from the Google Script editor, but for some reason, the email does not fire when I select "Complete" but IT WAS WORKING YESTERDAY!!!

Any tips?

M

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You probably can't do this with a simple trigger since sending email requires authorization.

```
var SHEET = "Live Jobs";
var VALUE = "Complete";
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 22
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()==SHEET){
    if(e.range.columnStart==COLUMN_NUMBER && e.value==VALUE){
        sh.hideRow(e.range.rowStart);
        SendEmail(e);
      }
    }
  }
}


function SendEmail(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.range.getSheet().getRange('Z1').getValue(), 'Invoice Job Alert', e.range.getSheet(e.range.rowStart,1,1,e.range.getSheet().getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].join(','));
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper,
I get an error message for the MailApp line:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 16, file "Code")"

Comment: Did you pass the event object from the onEdit function

Comment: Sorry Cooper, I'm not sure what you mean. Feeling very out of my depth...
Do I need to pass the event object to every cell in Column 22?

Comment: Look at my answer.  Do you have an e in both `sendEmail(e)` statements

Comment: Hi Cooper, your code still doesn't work for me! Thanks so much for your help so far. Do you have any suggestions for my amended code above?

Comment: It is working in the script editor but the email does not send when you select the "Complete" option within the live sheet. It was working yesterday (As in the email was sending, just not with the correct info). Any tips?

Comment: I suspect that you need to use and installable trigger and change the name of the function to something other than onEdit otherwise you will double trigger which can cause problems.